# HTML to XML conversion or a good HTML Parser Suggestion written in .Net

Tags: .net, xml, html-parsing

I need to parse html for a project and looking for a good html parser or an API providing conversion from html to xml.

Waiting for suggestions...

Thanks All...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is a .NET library that parses HTML files. The parser is very tolerant with "real world" malformed HTML. The object model is very similar to System.Xml.XmlDocument, but for HTML documents. It supports XPath and XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is very good